# Team Site Master page issue

Tags: master-page, team-sites

I'm activating the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature and after that I can change the master page (Settings -> Look and feel -> Master page) of this site.

- On Site Master Page I'm selecting seattle
- On System Master Page I'm selecting oslo

Its supposed to be different but both Site Master Page and System Master Page just apply the oslo master page. I don't know why. It happens even with my custom master page.

Comment: Please choose a nice title for your question.. This isn't helpful.. Search engines will go crazy too :)

Comment: When you set diffrent master pages for each System and site and then again go back into the "Master Page" menu from the site settings do you see OSLO master page set to both ? There is not much difference visually if you are looking for. OSLO does not have the left navigation whereas seattle has. Refer this [link](http://davidlozzi.com/2013/09/25/theres-more-than-meets-the-eye-differences-between-sharepoints-oslo-and-seattle-master-pages/) for more differences.

Comment: are you facing this issue on Subsite? if yes, you may probably have to mark check , update inherited subsites.

Answer (score 0):

They will not be different because the site was based on a team site template. Activating publishing will not change the template on which the site was originally built. Team Sites use system master page both for system pages such as "Site Settings" and for the main page.  (See http://sp2013.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-branding-team-sites-inherit.html)

Hope this helps